# How can we turn off a visual on report level filter

Tags: powerbi

Is there any way to turn off a visual when a report level filter is selected?

Or is there any alternative where I can achieve this ??

Comment: this may help: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Conditional-visibility-of-Power-BI-visual/m-p/161031

Comment: its not really helping as it should.

Comment: tldr: Not supported out of the box; You can use a workaround of placing a white visual on top (for example a treemap with a single white element) and trigger the element visibility based on the filter. when the white element is visible, it will hide elements under it. This probably will prevent you from being able to select those elements.

Comment: @User1 How about using [bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks)?